# GlassFish force 301 redirects instead of 302

Tags: domain, configuration, glassfish

My current setup has two `virtual-server`s, `my-server` redirects to the domain with `www.` prefix.

```
<virtual-server network-listeners="my-nlistener" id="my-server" sso-cookie-http-only="false" hosts="mydomain.com">
  <property name="redirect_1" value="from=/my-page.jsp url-prefix=http://www.mydomain.com/my-page.jsp"/>
  <property name="redirect_2" value="from=/about.jsp url-prefix=http://www.mydomain.com/about.jsp"/>      
</virtual-server>
<virtual-server network-listeners="my-nlistener" id="my-new-server" sso-cookie-http-only="false" hosts="www.mydomain.com">      
</virtual-server>
```

Unfortunately, for SEO compliance, I need to do `301` redirects and not `302`

How do I force `301` redirects in GlassFish like in Apache? Or is it a better practice to keep only one `virtual-server` and have multiple hosts as such : `<virtual-server id="my-new-server" hosts="www.mydomain.com, domain.com">`.

I would love to avoid creating a Spring application to do `301 redirects` for the specified pages.